# Работа с переменной полученной из переменной удалённого объекта

Tags: c++, ооп, память

```
int var1 = obj->count;//count - типа int
delete obj;
int var2 =var1;//можно ли инициализировать?
Function(var1);//или передавать в функцию?
```

Корректно ли так делать? Делаю так по несколько тысяч раз в своей программе.Не произойдёт ли со временем что-то плохое?

Comment: можно, скажем так:  значение из  obj->count скопировалось в var1

Comment: @ValeraKvip, то есть всё верно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, не произойдёт. Вы совершаете копирование переменной. На стеке создаётся переменная `var1`, которая инициализируется значением `obj->count`.